# Unable to stop MySQL on MAC

Tags: mysql, macos, exit

Whenever I click on the "Stop MySQL Server" on mac, it either can't stop or just restart.
However, rebooting will, but the minute I open the MySQL page, it starts up again!
I tried kill, shutdown on terminal but to no avail...

Comment: where do you click this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try these 3 commands below:

```
brew services stop mysql
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mysqladmin shutdown ?

Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html

http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/mysql/Shutdown-Server-with-mysqladmin.html